# Show and Hide handlers are applied multiple times on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<span id="username_{{ member.id }}" onclick="showMembershipData('{{ member.id }}');">{{ member.user.username }}</span>
```

and this is my jQuery code

```
function showMembershipData(id)
    {
        $("#memberInfo_"+id).slideDown();
        $("#username_"+id).click(function(){
            hideMembershipData(id);
        });
    }

    function hideMembershipData(id) {
        $("#memberInfo_" + id).slideUp();
        $("#username_" + id).click(function() {
            showMembershipData(id);
        });
    }
```

I want the user name to be clickable and when clicked open the "more information" pane, or close it if it is opened. What happens now is:

- username clicked for 1 time: pane opens.
- Clicked 2nd time: pane closes. Up to here is fine...
- clicked 3rd time pane opens and closes 2 times in a row (i.e. 4 operations: open, close, open, close)

and so on...  Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm... now that I see my code it seems to me that the .click() function does not override onclick="..." html attribute so they are both activated somehow. If this is the case then how can I workaround this issue?

Comment: use `$.unbind()` to remove unnessessary handlers as Nikhil propose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's change the code a little bit, shall we

```
<span 
    id="username_{{ member.id }}" 
    class="member"
    data-memberid="{{ member.id }}">{{ member.user.username }}</span>
```

on the jQuery side

```
$(".member").toggle(
    function() {  // click - show
        var id = $(this).attr("data-memberid");
        $("#memberInfo_" + id).stop().slideDown();
    },
    function() {  // click again - hide
        var id = $(this).attr("data-memberid");
        $("#memberInfo_" + id).stop().slideUp();

     });
```

easy :)

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning handler inside each handler, and you only need to assign handler once or even consider using event delegation `$.on(event, selector, handler)` if you are adding and removing items.

consider code below, and remove handlers from markup:

- add class `username` to elements with id `username_xxx`
- add class `memberInfo` to elements with id `memeberInfo_xxx`
- add `data-id` attribute to elements with id `username_xxx`

So markup going to look like:

```
 <span class="username" data-id"{{ member.id }}">{{ member.user.username }}</span>
```

And the script:

```
$('body').on('click', '.username', function(e) {
   var id = $(this).data('id') 
   $('#memberInfo_'+id).toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that even handlers are been attached multiple times. Basically with jQuery if you do something like

```
$("#element").click(functionName);
$("#element").click(functionName);
$("#element").click(functionName);
```

Then clicking the element once will fire functionName thrice! You need to refactor your code a bit to make sure that the event handlers are added and removed appropriately. Try this

```
function showMembershipData(id)
    {
        $("#memberInfo_"+id).slideDown();
        $("#username_"+id).unbind("click").bind("click",(function(){
            hideMembershipData(id);
        });
    }

    function hideMembershipData(id) {
        $("#memberInfo_" + id).slideUp();
        $("#username_" + id).unbind("click").bind("click",(function() {
            showMembershipData(id);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make life a whole lot easier by using jQuery's `slideToggle()` method - try the following:

```
function showMembershipData(id)
{
    $("#memberInfo_"+id).slideToggle();
}
```

This will toggle the `#memberInfo + id` (whatever the ID is) when the link is clicked. Can I suggest using jQuery's `click()` function? (needs a class added to the username `span`):

```
$("#username_span").click(function()
{
    $("#memberInfo_"+id).slideToggle();
});
```

Don't forget to add it to your `$(document).ready()` bit or whatever. Once you've done that, you can remove the `onClick` from the span.

James

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the guys above...you keep registering the events. If all you're doing is opening and closing one:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#book').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: slideToggle FTW - it makes stuff so much easier! Welcome to SO :-)

Comment: Well, thank Tux you haven't decided to join "Experts" Exchange! ;-)

Comment: lol! The day I join experts exchange is the day I stop programming

Comment: Same, but `str_replace("stop programming", "die");` (yes, I know it's missing an argument)

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you add an event handler each time `showMembershipData` gets called.
You should make sure only one event handler gets assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It is happenign 2 times in a row because each time you call those functions they bind a click function which fires.

try

```
$("#username_"+id).click(function(){ 
  var $showHideElement =$("#memberInfo_"+id);
  if ($showHideElementis(':visible'){
    $showHideElement.slideUp();
  }else{
    $showHideElement.slideDown();
  }
})
```